# `show create table` equivalent in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

In MySql you can see the table definition (columns with their data types etc) with `show create table table_name`.

Is there a similar functionality for oracle sql?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you are asking about SQL*Plus commands (`show create table table_name` doesn't appear to be a SQL statement), you can use the `desc` command

```
SQL> desc emp
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                           DATE
 SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                               NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)
```

If you really want a SQL statement, you can use the `dbms_metadata` package

```
  1  select dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'EMP', 'SCOTT' )
  2*   from dual
SQL> /

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','EMP','SCOTT')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."EMP"
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0),
        "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10),
        "JOB" VARCHAR2(9),
        "MGR" NUMBER(4,0),
        "HIREDATE" DATE,
        "SAL" NUMBER(7,2),
        "COMM" NUMBER(7,2),
        "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0),
         CONSTRAINT "PK_EMP" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPNO")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DE
FAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
  ALTER INDEX "SCOTT"."PK_EMP"  UNUSABLE ENABLE,
         CONSTRAINT "FK_DEPTNO" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPTNO")
          REFERENCES "SCOTT"."DEPT" ("DEPTNO") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DE
FAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
  CACHE
```

Depending on the tool you are using, you may need to run `set long 10000` first, that tells SQL*Plus to display the first 10,000 bytes of any LOB that is selected.  If your DDL is longer, set a larger value.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`DESC`](http://ss64.com/ora/desc.html):

```
DESC mytable
```

Will show you the columns, but unfortunately the create statement is not available using standard oracle tools.

Comment: @nightograph question doesn't ask for restrictions and keys; it only asks for *the table definition (columns with their data types etc)*

Comment: the question is asking for equivalent of "show create table" in Oracle, DESC is not equivalent since "show create" shows keys indexes and DESC doesn't

Answer (score 7):

```
SQL> set long 1000
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','TABLE NAME'[,'SCHEMA']) from DUAL
```

Comment: Answer contains errors, doesn't execute for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PL/SQL Developer; Right click on table, Select View, at the right bottom of the view window click on 'View SQL' button.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that table name is case_sensitive, you need to pass in table name as upper case.

Comment: I afraid this answer the 7 year's old question.

Comment: Akhnukh Khan, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score -2):

`DDL` is working for me and more simple all you need is to write `DDL (SCHEMA_OWNER).(TABLE_NAME)` ...for example `ddl HR.LOCATIONS;`....`HR` is the schema and `LOCATION` is table name ...make sure you write both the `SCHEMA` name and table `NAME` in capital  here  the output will be

```
CREATE TABLE "HR"."LOCATIONS" 
(   "LOCATION_ID" NUMBER(4,0), 
"STREET_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(40), 
"POSTAL_CODE" VARCHAR2(12), 
"CITY" VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT "LOC_CITY_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"STATE_PROVINCE" VARCHAR2(25), 
"COUNTRY_ID" CHAR(2), 
 CONSTRAINT "LOC_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("LOCATION_ID")
 USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 NOLOGGING COMPUTE 
STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "EXAMPLE"  ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "LOC_C_ID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("COUNTRY_ID")
  REFERENCES "HR"."COUNTRIES" ("COUNTRY_ID") ENABLE
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "EXAMPLE" ;
COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."LOCATIONS"."LOCATION_ID" IS 'Primary key of 
locations table';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."LOCATIONS"."STREET_ADDRESS" IS 'Street address 
of an office, warehouse, or production site of a company.
Contains building number and street name';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."LOCATIONS"."POSTAL_CODE" IS 'Postal code of 
the 
location of an office, warehouse, or production site
of a company. ';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."LOCATIONS"."CITY" IS 'A not null column that 
shows city where an office, warehouse, or
production site of a company is located. ';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."LOCATIONS"."STATE_PROVINCE" IS 'State or 
Province where an office, warehouse, or production site of a
company is located.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "HR"."LOCATIONS"."COUNTRY_ID" IS 'Country where an 
office, warehouse, or production site of a company is
located. Foreign key to country_id column of the countries table.';
COMMENT ON TABLE "HR"."LOCATIONS"  IS 'Locations table that contains 
specific address of a specific office,
warehouse, and/or production site of a company. Does not store 
addresses /
locations of customers. Contains 23 rows; references with the
departments and countries tables. ';
CREATE INDEX "HR"."LOC_CITY_IX" ON "HR"."LOCATIONS" ("CITY") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 NOLOGGING COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "EXAMPLE" ;
CREATE INDEX "HR"."LOC_COUNTRY_IX" ON "HR"."LOCATIONS" ("COUNTRY_ID") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 NOLOGGING COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "EXAMPLE" ;
CREATE INDEX "HR"."LOC_STATE_PROVINCE_IX" ON "HR"."LOCATIONS" 
("STATE_PROVINCE") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 NOLOGGING COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "EXAMPLE" ;
```

Comment: are you typing this command in SQL developer ? or sql plus ... also keep in mind you have to type the schema name with dot and then the table name ...for example `ddl HR.EMPLOYEES;` make sure the schema name and the table are in uppercase letters .

Comment: SQL Developer and they were in uppercase, but it might be that my tables are created underneath one of 30 in the ‘other users’ section below the schema.

Comment: yes just make sure the user you are logged under the correct user and have privilege to issue this command .

Comment: What privilege do I need? I only have select access.