# How to get a SQL script of a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get aSQL of a table?

I want the SQL. Can anybody tell me the `TABLE_NAME` where SQL is maintained?

I used SQL developer but is there any command or script or table name which shows the SQL of a table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264584/show-create-table-equivalent-in-oracle-sql

Comment: @Dba's answer is enough for your problem. Search for `DBMS_METADATA` package on Oracle Docs for further information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to spool the output of the below query,

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name)
     FROM USER_TABLES u;
```

Like,

```
set pagesize 0
set long 90000
set feedback off
set echo off 

spool schema.sql 

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name)
     FROM USER_TABLES u WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<your_table>';

spool off;
```

Reference: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_dbms_metadata.htm

Comment: The docs might be a better reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/metadata_api.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Oracle.  You can use `desc TABLE_NAME` in SQL*Plus.

More info in this question:
[`show create table` equivalent in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264584/show-create-table-equivalent-in-oracle-sql)

You should tag your question with only *one* DBMS

Comment: Any other option.....Any table contains the SQL....SYS table or user table

Comment: No, it's not contained in a table.  You need to use `desc`, `dbms_metadata` or `exp`

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer (3.2),once you find and double click on the table you want the SQL for,in the main window you will see a tab called as SQL which gives the SQL for that table.

```
1. Finding the table you want.
    i. Under Connections navigator, open your DB connection.
    ii. You will see an item called Tables.
    iii. Right click and say 'Apply filter' and add filter say 'Name = mytable'
```

Once you see your table under Tables item, double click on it and you will open a table editor in the main window.Open the SQL tab to get the table's Create SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate DDL script for table using SQL Developer.

1. Right click on table
2. Select Quick DDL Option
3. Select the output format you want (file/worksheet etc)