# ER arrows with cross specification in ER diagram

Tags: database, entity-relationship

A normal entity diagram usually use circles or a straight line to denote a zero or one to many relationship, respectively as in the following image:

[image]

However, recently I've seen something new, as in the following image, and was wondering what the cross means:

[image]

Comment: I draw that myself, however I picked up from an ER established database at work.

Comment: Are you able to inspect the database that _that_ ER diagram referred to? If so, just dump the foreign-key definitions and see if there's anything unusual about it.

Comment: hum I'm new to database logic, how would I do that ?

Comment: What DBMS is the database running in?

Comment: oracle db......

Comment: Use the `desc` command in Oracle to get object definitions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264584/show-create-table-equivalent-in-oracle-sql

Comment: I've done the following: `select * from all_cons_columns where table_name = <my_table_name>` and I got that the foreign key has a `SYS_*` constraint name and `TABLE_UK` and `TABLE_FK` i.e. unique and foreign (UF) key constraint. `desc` command just tells me `not null number(8)`

Comment: Sounds like the X refers to the `UNIQUE` constraint then.