# Error in SQL statement Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: oracle, power-automate-desktop

I am trying to connect ODBC 64bit Driver to allow me execute query to extract data from JDE 8.12
After building open SQL Connection and execute simple query it appear an error "Error in SQL statement Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

Could you please advise what is missing in order to allow the query to be execute?

Steps which I did:

1 - I selected Microsot OLE DB Provider for ODBC Driver

[image]

2-  Selected Driver (Driver - Oracle in OraClient 11g64_home1)

[image]

3 -Test The connection and show successful

4 - Build simple query to test the Flow

[image]

5- After run the Flow I get error

> "Error in SQL statement Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

After successful connection , I was expecting simple query to be executed without issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your Orale client is 32-bit only and the application using it is not x86 compiled.

Also, it's possible that you have a numeric field of certain limitation and a value is being computed arithmetically and then attempted to be stored into the field, overflowing its bounds.

Comment: Hi Lajos, Oracle Client is 64bit ( step1 connection was succefull ). I am running very simple query for testing only  SELECT * FROM PRODDTA.f0101

Comment: @RBV can you share the schema of the `PRODDTA.f0101` table?

Comment: select ABAN8
from PRODDTA.f0101
where ABAN8= ##### ( Customer number)

Comment: @RBV that's not the schema.

Comment: sorry. i dont know what is it. let me google

Comment: @RBV no worries. I wonder what fields your table has. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264584/show-create-table-equivalent-in-oracle-sql

Comment: He's asking for the table structure... provide the column names, datatypes, precision, scale, length, etc.. of the columns of this table. Particularly ABAN8. You can find this info in all_tab_columns

Comment: OWNER - PRODDTA ;
TABLE_NAME- F0101;
COLUMN_NAME - ABAN8;
DATA_TYPE - NUMBER;
DATA_LENGTH - 22;
DATA_SCALE 
NULLABLE - N;
COLUMN_ID - 1;
NUM_DISTINCT - 749681;
LOW_VALUE - C147;
HIGH_VALUE - C464646464;
DENSITY - 1.3339E-06;
NUM_NULLS - 0;
NUM_BUCKETS - 1;
SAMPLE_SIZE - 749681;
GLOBAL_STATS - YES;
USER_STATS - NO;
AVG_COL_LEN - 6;
CHAR_LENGTH - 0;
CHAR_USED 
V80_FMT_IMAGE - NO;
DATA_UPGRADED - YES;
HISTOGRAM - NONE;

additinoal info https://jde.erpref.com/?schema=920&system=01&table=F0101

Comment: @RBV the query is simple indeed but the table is not simple. Can you run your query for only a subset of your fields? Do you get the same error then?

Comment: if consider subset  "Where' clause then I did before like this  select ABAN8 from PRODDTA.f0101 where ABAN8= #####  and gave me same error in PowerAutomate Desktop

Comment: @RBV I asked about a subset of columns, you answered about a test with a filter. Can you run a query like `SELECT ABAN8 FROM F0101` ?

Comment: Hi Lajos, i did it before and did work. Gives me error "Error in SQL statement ERROR [42S02] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

Comment: @RBV Your table or view does not exist, so it was dropped for some reason, at least according to the error message

Comment: correct becuase it's missing the proddta. guess

Comment: @RBV you will need to perform the experiment of running a query that loads only a part of the fields where the table or view actually exists.