# Different count(*) from same table when queried by different users

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run:

```
select count(*)
from my_table;
```

I get two different non-zero numbers returned when I run it as two different users.

What could cause this?

More information about the table:
[image]

Comment: 1) Is something else inserting or deleting rows? If no, how are you sure? 2) Are the two users in a transaction where they have inserted or deleted rows?

Comment: Do the users have their own tables, with different data? Or synonyms to different tables? Or do you have VPD set up against the table? Or uncommitted data? Are you sure they're both connecting to the same database?

Comment: @AlexPoole Only 1 table, No synonyms. No uncommitted data at least on my user. Don't know what a VPD is, checking that.

Comment: Is there any row level security on the table? Showing us the schema would help.

Comment: @Schwern 1) no, there's a trigger that says when updates happened, and the user that's showing more data has data from a while ago that isn't showing on my account.  2) My user isn't in the middle of a transaction, checking the other user now...

Comment: @Schwern regarding row-level security, would my user by able to see that (my user is the one showing fewer rows)

Comment: @Schwern This is in Banner, the Ellucian tool, there are thousands of tables in the schema, so I can't really show the schema.

Comment: @DavidOneill Can you show us the schema for just that table, please?

Comment: @Schwern what does it mean to show a schema for just that table? https://imgur.com/a/iFqV8FX is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Or this? https://imgur.com/a/3Npy1gM

Comment: The former, `desc tablename`. The more complete [show create table equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18264638/14660) would also be useful. Is it possible the database is replicated and one user is connecting a replica that's behind?

Comment: It turns out it was a VPD issue.  @AlexPoole I'll accept it if you put that into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your access is restricted by Oracle's [Virtual Private Database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/using-oracle-vpd-to-control-data-access.html) functionality, providing row-level security.

You presumably have a [function to generate a dynamic `where` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/using-oracle-vpd-to-control-data-access.html#GUID-532B05E7-2E08-4D8A-96B0-7F6EDD75DD14).

You can [query the data dictionary](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/using-oracle-vpd-to-control-data-access.html#GUID-09300037-0440-4212-B28A-1EABEA6ABDB2) to see exactly what is set up in your database, assuming you (or your colleague) have the necessary privileges to see that information.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a user can see uncommitted changes that were created in their session and other sessions (even belonging to the same user) will not see those uncommitted changes. Therefore, if a user has `INSERT`ed or `DELETE`d rows in the table you are querying and has not used a `COMMIT` statement then they will see a different number of rows to other users.